# as3 - detecting an out-of-range value w/ parseInt()

Tags: actionscript-3, string, integer, range

if i pass parseInt() a string representing an integer larger than 2^31,
how do i detect that ?

it would be swell if parseInt() returned NaN,
but it doesn't.

i could test the number which parseInt returns against max int & min int.

anything better ?

tia,
orion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could turn it into a Number first, which can be way way bigger than int, check it against int.MAX_VALUE and int.MIN_VALUE, and then finally cast it to int.

```
var myNumber:Number = Number(myStringOrSomething);
var myInt:int;
if (myNumber <= int.MAX_VALUE && myNumber >= int.MIN_VALUE) {
    // Number is big (or small) enough, cast it as int
    myInt = Math.round(myNumber) as int;
} else {
    // Failed at converting to int
}
```

Comment: thanks Flassari. that's what i did. parseInt() actually returns a Number, not an int.

Answer (score 1):

If you are assuming the maximum value of return value to be **4,294,967,295** (Max value for uint) then you are mistaken.

The function parseInt returns a Number & not a uint. The maximum value for a Number is **1.79e+308** which is quite large & still if your number is above that, the function parseInt will return NaN.

So you can simply check for NaN & it should work.

Comment: i'm actually converting to int, not uint.

parseInt() only returns NaN for invalid numeric strings like "hello" (base 10). for strings representing values out of range of integer it just returns the Number representing the value. .. which when you then cast it to an int can yield very bad results.

i ended up testing the return against NaN, and for being in the range [int.MIN_VALUE, int.MAX_VALUE].

Comment: Well the title says "detecting an out-of-range value of parseInt()" & not "detecting out of range value of an integer" or rather a custom set of strings. Anyways, I guess your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

i ended up testing the return against NaN, and also for being in the range [int.MIN_VALUE, int.MAX_VALUE].

here's some examples and the results. (false = not a valid int, true = is a valid int)

```
"abcde"      , false //
"0XYZ"       , true  // i wish this wasn't the case, but it is.
" 123 "      , true  //
"NaN"        , false //
"85899345912", false //   2^33 - 1
 "2147483647", true  //   2^31 - 1
 "2147483648", false //   2^31
"-2147483647", true  // -(2^31 - 1)
"-2147483648", true  // -(2^31
"-2147483649", false // -(2^31 + 1)
```